# Is there anyway to shut down inactive PC automatically as soon as computation finishes?

Tags: hold

Instead of running PC whole night when computation stops somewhere in middle of night, is there anyway to shut down PC automatically few moments after computation running completes.

Comment: You can execute a shell command for the OS inside Mathematica using "Run". E.g. on Windows you could say: Run["cmd /C shutdown"]

Answer (score 2):

suppose your script like this:

```
Pause[1];
Echo[1];
```

name it `tmp.wls`

```
wolframscript -f tmp.wls  || echo 111
```

gives

```
>> 1
111
```

then change `echo 111` to `shutdown`